# Не могу нажать на скрытый элемент Python+selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Всем привет. Есть следующая проблема: Тестирую сайт, на нём более половины форм для ввода скрыты, и появляются только при наведении  на них мышкой.

Для этого пытался использовать следующий код:

```py
def test_one():
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('host')
        invisability_elem = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'id_elem')))
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(invisability_elem).perform()
        invisability_elem.click()
```

Всегда получаю ошибку `rect is undefined`

Ожидания тут не помогают, т.к элемент находит без проблем, а взаимодействовать с ним не может....

Уже всё перерыл, ничего не рабоатет. Браузер Firefox - 70

Answer (score 1):

В общем решил проблему конструкцией

```py
vis_elem1 = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'id_viselem'))
invis_elem2 = WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'id_invisviselem2'))
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(vis.elem1).perform()
invisability_elem.click()
```

Элемент на который необходимо кликнуть `invis_elem2`

Теперь подробнее: в моём случае у меня была следуюущая иерархия htm страницы

```html
<div id='parent_elem' class="parrent">
    <div id="vis_elem1" class = "subprrent">
       <div id="invis_elem1" class="subparrent"/>
    <div id="vis_elem2" class="subparrent">
       <div id="invis_elem2" class="subparrent"/>
```

Элементы `invis_elem1` и `invis_elem2` имели css атрибут `dispaly=none`, в моём случае элемент `invis_elem2` становился видимым только при наведении на `vis_elem1`. В используемом мной Firefox v70, это можно наблюдать, ели в панели разработчика, навести мышкой на htm код `vis_lem1`, тогда строка html `invis_elem2` становится "видимой" (до этого строка была серой)